# Wie bezeichnet man irreführende Begriffe wie “Landfleischerei”?

Tags: single-word-request, phrase-request

Besonders beim Einkaufen trifft man all zu oft auf Bezeichnungen wie das Wort “*Landfleischerei*”, das wohl eine ländliche Idylle suggerieren soll, aber inhaltlich (glaube ich) genau dasselbe wie “*Fleischerei*” bedeutet<sup>1</sup>. Ähnliches gilt für Markennamen wie “*Wiesenhof*”.

Gibt es auf Deutsch einen linguistischen oder rhetorischen Fachbegriff für solche Nomina? Falls nicht, wie bezeichnet man sie am besten? Ich suche einen Begriff oder Ausdruck der deutlich ausdruckt daß man nicht nur Schönfärberei sondern eine Täuschungsabsicht unterstellt.

Es geht nicht darum ob in einem konkreten Fall “*Landfleischerei*” in Täuschungsabsicht gebraucht wird, sondern wie man die Meinung daß es so ist ausdruckt. Ich glaube schon daß manch einer sein Betrieb einigermaßen arglos so bezeichnet, aber daß besonders im Supermarkt eine Art Täuschung sehr wohl beabsichtigt ist.

#### P.S.

Ich habe [single-word-request](/questions/tagged/single-word-request) *und* [phrase-request](/questions/tagged/phrase-request) verwendet, aber mir ist natürlich egal welche es wird.

<sup>1</sup> <sub>“*Landfleischerei*” könnte vielleicht auch bedeuten “*Fleischerei auf dem Lande*” — also nicht in der Stadt — aber wo möglicherweise (oder sogar wahrscheinlich) dennoch Tiere aus der Massentierhaltung verarbeitet werden.</sub>

Comment: Ich wüsste jetzt nicht, was an der "Landfleischerei" (und am Wiesenhof) behaupten würde, das **kein** Fleisch aus Massentierhaltung verwendet wird. Bei einer "Stadtfleischerei" stelle ich mir irgendwie weniger Tiere vor.

Comment: @tofro: Natürlich wird das nicht explizit behauptet, aber andere Assoziationen werden aufgerufen die diesen Gedanken in den Hintergrund drängen, und vielleicht ein Bild van Tieren auf dem offenen _Lande_ oder auf einer _Wiese_ im Vordergrund setzen.

Comment: @tofro: In der Stadtfleischerei gibt es nur Hund und Katze, Hamster und Kanari. :) Das sehe ich auch so.

Comment: Bei der *Landfleischerei* finde ich interessant, dass die entsprechende Firma vermutlich argumentieren kann, dass ihre Anlage (eine lebensmittelindustrielle Großschlachterei) durchaus auf dem Lande steht. Die Großen der Branche haben ihre Betriebe (wo dann 3000 ungelernte Arbeiter über Ketten von Subunternehmen beschäftigt sind) oft wirklich in sehr abgelegenen Gebieten...

Comment: Der Begriff muss ja gar nicht irreführend sein.

Answer (score 6):

Das ist ein [Euphemismus](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemismus), Wikipedia beschreibt ihn so: "...ein sprachlicher Ausdruck, der eine Person, eine Personengruppe, einen Gegenstand oder einen Sachverhalt beschönigend, mildernd oder in verschleiernder Absicht benennt."

Das ist eine rhetorische Figur oder auch Stilmittel, auch hier sei auf den interessanten Wikipedia-Artikel mit der Liste der [rhetorischen Stilmittel](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_rhetorischer_Stilmittel) verwiesen, sehr lesenswert.

Comment: Ich hatte nicht an _Euphemismus_ gedacht; danke für den Hinweis! Mir scheint daß die **verschleiernder** Absicht eher im Deutschen als im Englischen (meiner Muttersprache) verstanden wird, was mir nicht bewußt war. Wir würden nämlich “_Euphemism_” nicht so oft gebrauchen wenn eine Täuschung Absicht wäre, was dem englischen Wikipedia Artikel zu entnehmen ist, obwohl das in Fällen wie “_enhanced interrogation_” = _Tortur_ durchaus so ist. Außerdem gibt es vielleicht einen anderen Terminus der die Alternativen _beschönigend_, _mildernd_ ausschließt. Bislang also ein ▲ aber noch nicht √!

Comment: Why would you think that "euphemism" in English has a different meaning?

Comment: Euphemismus stellt nicht unbedingt eine Täuschung dar, bzw. wird diese nicht immer unbedingt beabsichtigt. Es ist eher eine Überhöhung für eine Tatsache, die bei näherer Betrachtung dem Versprochenem nicht stand hält. Ich würde also sagen etwas schwächer als Täuschung. Manchmal wird es auch ein bisschen anders benutzt, so daß man es wirklich merkt. Das Gesagte ist dann eindeutig ironisch oder sarkastisch.

Comment: @tink: I do not say that _euphemism_ has a different meaning in English, but that the nuances in meaning occur with different frequency. I have always thought of a euphemism primarily as an expression used to avoid explicitly naming something because of a taboo or out of respect for the presumed feelings of ones hearers or of oneself. In this case there is no intent to deceive. At the same time it can be used deceitfully, as in _enhanced interrogation_ meaning _torture_.

Comment: @Thomas: Das sind eben Gründe warum _Euphemismus_ nicht perfekt paßt: weil es die andere Nuancen auch zuläßt und weil “Täuschung nicht immer beabsichtigt ist”.

Comment: @tink: What I also forgot to say: while the first sentence of German Wikipedia mentions _verschleiernder Absicht_, [English Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphemism) merely refers to “things the user wishes to downplay”, which I find significantly weaker.

Comment: Onkel Duden (dem ich mehr trauen würde als einem Eintrag in der Plethipedia) definiert *Euphemismus* als *beschönigende, verhüllende, mildernde Umschreibung für ein anstößiges oder unangenehmes **Wort***. Wenn man dieser Definition folgt, geht es also nicht um die Anstößigkeit der Sache, sondern um die Anstößigkeit des Worts, und da *Großschlachterei* jedenfalls kein anstößiges **Wort** ist (wenn auch eventuell eine problematische Sache) könnte man zum Schluss kommen, dass *Euphemismus* hier nicht richtig passt.

Comment: @PJTraill Du hattest explizit nach dem rhetorischen Begriff gefragt, das ist nun mal die beste Annäherung daran. Man kann es sich hin und her deuten und es gibt sicher Leute, die den Fokus anders setzen, aber ich glaube näher kommt man nicht ran. Sprache ist nun mal begrenzt und der Euphemismusbegriff erfasst es schon ganz gut.

Comment: *Euphemismus* klingt hier falsch.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Mit Verlaub, aber du siehst das falsch herum, Duden sagt: "Mit einem Euphemismus wird etwas, was eine möglicherweise anstößige oder unangenehm wirkende Bezeichnung hat, beschönigt, verhüllt oder sprachlich gemildert." Es geht halt gerade um eine Sache, die durch ein beschönigendes Wort oder eine Rede "vertuscht" wird.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Mach mir Wikipedia nicht schlecht, ich sehe es als eine der bedeutensten Dinge der neuerlichen menschlichen Entwicklung an, bei aller Kritikwürdigkeit. Sorry. das musste so schnulzig raus. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Euphemismus wäre auch meine erste Antwort.

Richtet man sich aber an weniger gebildete Leser und Zuhörer und will die eigene Bildung nicht zur Schau stellen, kann man auch gut mit Substantivierungen dessen arbeiten, was Thomas als Erklärung teils schon genannt hat:

- Verharmlosung
- Beschönigung
- Verschleierung

Comment: Danke für die andere Vorschläge. **_Verharmlosung_** finde ich sehr passend, weil es darauf hindeutet daß der Sprecher sich sehr wohl von etwas schlechtem bewußt ist und probiert zu verhindern daß der Hörer darauf kommt. _Beschönigung_ weniger, weil es auch ein Euphemismus aus Rücksicht auf den Gefühlen der Anderen (oder die eigenen) sein könnte. _Verschleierung_ auch etwas weniger, weil das Element _harmlos_ fehlt: es macht nicht deutlich daß der Gegenstand eben nicht harmlos ist.

Comment: Was harmlos ist und was nicht ist Ansichtssache.

Comment: Ich finde "Landfleischerei" ziemlich harmlos. Die Fleischerei muss ja nicht etwas verschleiern. Das ist höchstens eine Vermutung.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Vielleicht hat sie was zu verschleiern; Zustände. Was soll das "Land" in Landfleischerei? Wegen der Mieten dürften alle Großfleischereien auf dem Land sein, aber was interessiert es den Kunden? Landliebe? Ich denke es sollen romantische Vorstellungen evoziert werden, und zwar auf subtile Weise, denn sobald man drüber nachdenkt kommt man drauf, dass Lidl für Millionen Kunden kaum in einer gemütlichen Eckfleischerei im Dorfkern einkaufen wird.

Comment: @userunknown: Das "Land" ist da drin weil sie ja nicht in der Stadt ist. Warum soll eine Landfleischerei eigentlich eine unethische Großfleischerei sein? Der Begriff an sich ist m.E. völlig in Ordnung. Wenn der Begriff missbraucht wird ist das eben Missbrauch. Und ja, Firmen, ob groß oder klein, ob ethisch oder nicht, suchen sich natürlich einen schönen, vorteilhaften Namen aus.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Habe ich unethisch gesagt? Ich kann was über unethisches Kolportieren sagen. Nein, das Land ist nicht drin, weil es nicht in der Stadt ist, denn eine Fleischerei hat massig Attribute, die man in den Namen aufnehmen könnte aber es ist nicht jedes Attribut im Namen, das zutrifft. Solange die Fleischereien auf dem Land sind ist der Begriff sachlich in Ordnung, da stimme ich vollkommen zu, aber das ist nicht der Grund dafür, dass er auch gewählt wird. Großfleischerei trifft wahrscheinlich auch zu aber wurde nicht gewählt. Firmen suchen sich schöne Namen und Kunden bleiben skeptisch.

Comment: Natürlich ist das nicht nur der einzige Grund, dass der Name gewählt wird. "Land-" klingt immer gut. Ist eben ein Marketingbegriff. Der muss aber nicht unbedingt irreführend sein.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Und habe ich behauptet, dass der Begriff unbedingt irreführend sein muss?

Answer (score 3):

Bei solchen Bezeichnungen, die dem Verbraucher mehr suggerieren sollen als tatsächlich dahintersteckt, spricht man auch von einem **Marketingbegriff**.

Comment: Ja. Bei der *Landfleischerei* (für einen vermutlich industrielle Großschlachterei) finde ich *Marketingbegriff* passender als Euphemismus. Ich glaube, weil ich *Euphemismus* eher beziehen würde auf Bezeichnungen für Klassen von Dingen (*Entsorgungspark* statt *Atommüllfabrik*), nicht für Eigennamen, und die *Landschlachterei* scheint mir stark in Richtung eines Eigennamens zu gehen (welchen die betreffende Firma sich gibt).

Comment: Man könnte sogar fast meinen, dass *Fleischerei* schon beschönigend für *Schlachterei* ist, aber das würde wohl zu weit führen. Nichtsdestotrtoz glaube ich, dass die Entscheidung zwischen diesen beiden Wörtern sehr bewusst gefällt wurde.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: Guter Punkt. _Geht **in Richtung** Eigenname_ ist richtig: sie tun als ob es ein sinnvoller Begriff ist während es nichts wesentliches an _Fleischerei_ zufügt, wenigstens nichts ehrliches, und es wird fast ausschließlich als Teil von einem Firmen- oder Markennamen gebraucht.

Comment: @RoyPJ: _Fleischerei_ könnte verschleiernd gemeint sein, aber es kann auch damit zu tun haben ob ein Betrieb nur schachtet, nur Geschlachtetes  weiterverarbeitet oder beides tut. Übrigens gibt es auch “_Landschlachtereien_”.

Answer (score 2):

Im Grunde könnte man von

> Vorspiegelung falscher Tatsachen

sprechen, auch wenn dies zunächst ein Begriff aus dem Strafgesetzbuch ist und hier - zur Bezeichnung von Produkt- und Firmennamen, die dem Kunden eine falsche Idylle vorspiegeln - in einem Feld noch unterhalb der Strafbarkeit (Betrug) verwendet würde.

Außerdem will die Firma sich und ihre Produktionsbedingungen natürlich

> schönreden

und die Kunden

> hinters Licht führen

oder

> einlullen

und sich damit

> aufhübschen

Geht man kognitionswissenschaflich an die Sache ran, könnte man auch von

> Framing oder Reframing

sprechen: Ein Ding wird über eine bestimmte Bezeichnung für dieses Ding in einen anderen Kontext gestellt; hier den Kontext eines stereotypischen, idyllischen Bilderbuchlandlebens mit friedlich grasenden Kühen, das sich deutlich unterscheidet von der - hier mal vermuteten - agrar- und lebensmittelindustriellen Wirklichkeit eines modernen, großen Schlachtbetriebs, der hauptsächlich von Subunternehmerketten mit Personal beschickt wird, das armselig wohnt und die Landessprache nicht gut kennt.

Comment: So ganz stimme ich dem nicht zu. Ich denke schon, dass jene Fleischereien auf dem Land angesiedelt sind (was hätte es auch für einen Vorteil, sie mitten in der Stadt zu bauen..). Es ist also nicht unbedingt eine falsche Tatsache, sondern das, was wir uns darunter vorstellen, ist falsch. Und das wird natürlich bewusst eingesetzt.

Comment: @RoyPJ  Ja, verstehe. Jedoch: Als falsche Tatsachen, die hier vorgespiegelt werden, sehe ich weniger die geographische Lage der Schlachterei sondern die Bild- und Vorstellungswelten, die mit dem Begriff *Landfleischerei* einhergehen (Gras, Sonne, Bauernhof, Kühe, Friede, Freude, Eierkuchen). Aber ich gebe zu, dass das weniger *Tatsachen* sind, eher *Vorstellungen*.  Vielleicht also **Vorspiegelung falscher Vorstellungen**?

Comment: **(Re)Framing** ist interessant/nützlich.